# Cancel Query in remote ssms from ssms in my pc

Tags: sql-server, ssms, remote

We connect to our customer's database server with vpn. Sometimes we manage Sql server to connect database server or to connect with ssms in our pc's.
 
I executed a query with ssms in database server, then the connection has gone down. I have tried to connect many times but failed. I have to cancel this query. 
I can connect with ssms in my pc's.
Can I cancel query with ssms in my pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**  Get query session id using below query

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,----- SPID
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time,req.start_time,db_name(database_id) DatabaseName
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
where [status] <> 'background'
and command<> 'TASK MANAGER'
```

[image]

**Step 2:** use kill command to kill the process execution

```
Kill(53) -- KIll (SPID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [KILL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) (SPID) to kill the query.